# HTML: форма без атрибута action

Tags: php, javascript, html

Здравствуйте!

На некоторых сайта есть формы без атрибута `action`. Например:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform" method="post">
</form>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом реализуется отправка данных на сервер? С помощью JavaScript присваивается URL? Или как-то по другому?

Буду признателен, если приведете пример. Спасибо!

Comment: Данные отправляются по адресу открытой страницы без указания action.

Comment: может быть ajax

Comment: @Visman т.е. Через Ajax отправляются данные, на сервере принимаются. Если все хорошо, то через JavaScript осущестсвляется редирект?

Comment: Я написал про стандартное поведение формы. Если данные у вас через ajax отправляются, то нужно смотреть, что указано в javascript целью для отправки данных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Если не указано, куда слать, то стандарт требует слать на текущий адрес.
2. Всегда можно при помощи js наделать чего угодно.

Answer (score 1):

Отправка осуществляется просто через AJAX. Например

```js
$("form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  //Какая нить валидация
  if (true) {
    var action = $(this).data('action');
    var data = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.post(action, data);
  }
});
```

```html
<form data-action='/simple.php'>
  <input type="text" name="a" value="1" id="a">
  <input type="submit" name="g" value="Submit" id="g">
</form>
```

А причина простая, меньше ботов будет спамить